# How to create mySQL trigger after deduction of days?

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
CREATE TABLE `leaveinformation`(
`leave_id` CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
`annualleave` INT(2) DEFAULT NULL,
`sickleave` INT(2) DEFAULT NULL,
`maternityleave` INT(3) DEFAULT NULL,

//table for trigger
CREATE TABLE Leave_Balance (
`leave_id` CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
`annualleave` INT(2) DEFAULT NULL,
`sickleave` INT(2) DEFAULT NULL,
`maternityleave` INT(3) DEFAULT NULL,
`day_applied` INT(2) DEFAULT NULL,
`leave_type` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
);



//create trigger
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `After_Deduct_Day`
AFTER UPDATE ON LeaveInformation
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
UPDATE ON Leave_Balance
Leave_ID = OLD.Leave_ID;
IF leave_type=AnnualLeave then
Set AnnualLeave = OLD.AnnualLeave - day_applied,
IF leave_type=SickLeave
Set SickLeave = OLD.SickLeave - day_applied,
ELSE
Set Maternity Leave = OLD.MaternityLeave - day_applied,



END$$
DELIMITER;
```

i want to create a trigger that after applicants apply their leave type (annualleave/maternityleave/sickleave), it will deduct the days they applied from the balance of their leave. but i can't figure out the correct code.

Comment: Presumably only approved leave gets into the table?

Comment: yes. only approved leave will made changes.

Comment: So you update `leaveinformation` and you want `leave_balance` to change accordingly, for the same `leave_id`.

But it looks like for each leave_id it's possible to have all three kinds of leave? So basically you can change more than one leave at the same time? Right?

Comment: So while leave is unapproved, how does a user know how much leave they (potentially) have left?

Comment: yes. each leave_id will have 3 kinds of leave except male employees only have 2 and NULL on maternityleave.

Comment: @Strawberry, they can view their leaveinformation to see how many days left. before the deduction on trigger took place, in this case, it is unapproved.

Comment: I think your table design needs work. Try to popuplate it with some values to see if it makes sense, before you try to create a trigger.

Make sure that all the information in leave_balance comes from leaveinformation, as that is what the trigger can work on.

Comment: I don't understand how that works in practice. :-(

Comment: Take a look at the mysql-documentation of the trigger, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html, and fix your syntax. `UPDATE ON Leave_Balance
Leave_ID = OLD.Leave_ID;` makes no sense there. See last example (testref), it is an insert-trigger, not an update-trigger, but updates another table, just as you try to do here. And I guess you meant to use  (or include) the trigger on insert anyway, because otherwise, the `insert` to `leaveinformation` won't update the balance. But as you left out half the table and didn't describe what inserts/updates the data, it's just a guess.

Comment: And as a second note: why would you do such process? You can get the balance values by just taking the sum over all applications (e.g. create a view, use sum and group by leave_id, although i don't understand the leave_type-column in your balance-table). But that's another guess on how your application works, since you didn't specify that. But you HAVE TO have a table where all past `leaveinformation` are stored, so that information has to be somewhere.